# To match any characters except '\n' string

Tags: regex

i want to match the word 'mi_edit' if it's preceded by a '#' , so it should match :

```
# update icon of mi_edit
```

but i don't want to match if there are any '\n' in between the '#' and 'mi_edit' . So it shouldn't match any of these :

```
# update icon \nof mi_edit
#\nupdate \nicon of mi_edit
# update\nicon of mi_edit
```

Comment: Still, this question is a little bit misleading. Do you mean literally the characters `\n` or do you mean a newline?

Comment: i mean literal \n, not newline

Answer (score 0):

You can use negative lookahead for `\n` (`\` has to be escaped):

```
^(?:(?!\\n).)+$
```

Answer (score 0):

It's so simple just `/#.+(mi_edit)/g`

```
let txt = `
# update icon of mi_edit
# update icon \nof mi_edit
#\nupdate \nicon of mi_edit
# update\nicon of mi_edit
# update icon of mi_edit
`
console.log(txt.match(/#.+(mi_edit)/g))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `$` sign at the end of your regex.
This means the should end if a new line.

The Regex:

> #.*mi_edit$

will only match your first example. All the other do not match.
Tested with: https://regex101.com/

You can also add `^` at the beginning before the `#`. This means that the string should also start with `#`.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use the following regex:

```regex
\A[^\n]*#[^\n]*(mi_edit)\Z

\A         # From the start of the string
[^\n]*     # Any character, any times, which is not a new line
#          # Literal '#'
[^\n]*     # Any character, any times, which is not a new line
(mi_edit)  # Capture 'mi_edit' in the 1st capture group
\Z         # To the end of the string

# A string that has no new lines from start to end,
# and which contains a '#' before 'my_edit'
```

`^...$` asserts "start/end of the **line**", but here you want the start/end of the **string**

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer:

```
#(?:(?!\\n).)*?mi_edit
```

Use negative lookahead **(?!\\n)**

It will match any #XXXmi_edit , where XXX can be anything but '\n'. It will reject if there's literal '\n' anywhere in between **#** and **mi_edit**.